# Creating a User entity while decoupling ASP.NET Core Identity from the Domain layer according to Onion Architecture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-identity, onion-architecture

I am creating a project where I need to use Identity within the Onion Architecture, and I am having a problem. My schema requires a User entity that would obviously have relations with other entities.

I can't figure out how to define this `ApplicationUser` entity that is supposed to inherit from the `IdentityUser` class like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }
```

all within the Domain layer so I could relate it to other entities defined there while keeping the Domain independent of ASP.NET Core Identity.

Is there a way to do this or is this just an inescapable coupling?

Comment: The Domain project project reference is provided on other projects and this way it becomes accessible. You can then use ApplicationUser class. Check implementation of Clean Architecutre repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/yogyogi/Ardalis-Clean-Architecture-Implementation).